# Allow Outlook 2007 to edit custom shared iCalendars

Tags: python, apache, webdav, outlook-2007, icalendar

I have been working on some custom shared Internet calendar software. I currently have a webdav server setup using apache and my software (using python) and right now it works great with Thunderbird and the Lightning plugin, I can subscribe to an icalendar and edit events with no problem. However I've run into a snag with Outlook 2007. I can currently read an icalendar but it sets that calendar in Outlook 2007 to read only. Doing some searching I've come across some findings saying that setting up some webdav server stuff on a Windows machine I can get the machine to tell Outlook 2007 that the calendar can be editted as well (basically turn off the read only and allow that icalendar to be published). I'm currently trying to set the server up to work with but thought I might ask SO to speed up my research a bit.

My question basically is, is there some header information or something else that I can send in my response back to Outlook to let it know an Internet calendar has write privaleges? I know in general it is controlled by the client whether an icalendar can be written to since I can read and write these same calendars just fine in Thunderbird.

Additionally, I have heard this read/write problem with Internet calendars have been solved in Outlook 2010 but upgrading to that is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Outlook 2007 seems to have no ability to allow writing to an Internet Calendar. Icalendars are set to read only. You can publish a calendar to a webdav to create your own icalendar but that calendar (in your Outlook '07) would never update if someone else were to somehow edit that calendar (on the server). It would always just overwrite it when it makes a 'PUT' to the server.